# Create static library from existing project (VS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

I created a C++ project in Visual Studio (I chose "Empty Project"). Now, I want to export it as a library, so I can use the classes in other projects. What I want is a "Header Files" folder (well, that's easy) and a .lib file. However, I still want the project to remain executable for testing. The only difference between the library-project and the executable one would be my "main.cpp" file. Is there an easy way to do exactly that, Without screwing up the project settings completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all your files into a new static lib, make your exe just a thin wrapper and link with the static lib

Comment: Isnt there another way? Something like compilation profiles?

Comment: it would be more complicated